# Passing data that users can't change from form to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have this form:

```
<%= form_for(@book) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area 'review' %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag "book[title]", result.title %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag "book[author]", result.author %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag "book[pages]", result.pages %>
    <%= f.submit "Add book" %>
<% end %>
```

In books_controller I have a `create` action to add a book.

I don't want the user to be able to change the book's title, author, or pages. The only thing that I want the user's input is the review.

I know that hidden_field_tags are easily tampered with - they can be changed in browsers such as Chrome or Firefox by inspecting the code and changing the value. This would result in the user being able to change the data.

How do I pass data to the `create` action of the controller without the user being able to change the data?

Comment: How you get result object ??

Comment: @Thorin `result` is a OpenStruct from an outside API

Comment: I was asking becsuse as those values are in hidden fields then you can save those values in controller directly in create or update method no need to pass in hiddens if you can call same api on create method

Answer (score 0):

You can use `text_field_tag` with a `readonly: true` option.

```
<%= form_for(@book) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area 'review' %>
  <%= text_field_tag "book[title]", result.title, readonly: true %>
  <%= text_field_tag "book[author]", result.author, readonly: true %>
  <%= text_field_tag "book[pages]", result.pages, readonly: true %>
  <%= f.submit "Add book" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: The readonly option has the same limitation that the hidden field has - in some browsers the user can inspect and modify the property

Answer (score 0):

I would pass the book ID in a hidden field and then look up all the other book attributes in the controller.

```
<%= form_for(@book) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area 'review' %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag "book[id]", result.id %>
    <%= f.submit "Add book" %>
<% end %>
```

If you are concerned with the user still being able to change the ID of the book in the hidden field, you can perform a check in the controller to see if the user is authorized to enter a review of the book with the ID submitted.